# Paginate Iron-Ajax response

Tags: polymer, iron-ajax

I would like to paginate the iron ajax response but I didn't succeed until now. Any help

```
 <template is="dom-bind">
      <iron-ajax auto url="test2.json"
       params = '{"A":"5", "B":"888"}'
      handle-as="json" last-response="{{signups}}"></iron-ajax>
      <vaadin-grid items="{{signups}}">
        <table>
          <colgroup>
            <col name="A"/>
            <col name="B"/>
          </colgroup>
        </table>
      </vaadin-grid>
    </template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like `params = "[[_getParams(A,B,page)]]"`, then everytime you page++ a new call will be made with the latest params from _getParams()